# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on remote windows machine

Tags: out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have developed a java program which i have deployed on remote machine and it has latest jre1.8.0_60 installed. I have developed the program using jdk1.8.0_60. I have tested the program on my machine (memory 6GB-64bit) and on my colleagues computer (memory 8GB-64bit) and the program executed without any problem but when i execute the same program on remote machine(memory 4GB-64BIT) it throws this error:

```
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
   Dumping heap to java_pid3696.hprof ...
   Heap dump file created [217326007 bytes in 2.721 secs]
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(Unknown Source)
    at Invoice.GetInvoicesByStatusAndDate(Invoice.java:66)
    at ClientSAAJ.GetInvoicesByStatusAndDate(ClientSAAJ.java:75)
    at ClientSAAJ.main(ClientSAAJ.java:10)
```

Could it be that there is not enough ram or do i have carry out some sort of java configuration?

Comment: Both could be. Or maybe you pass different data to the program on server(big database maybe). But as I can see from stacktrace you are building a large `String` (and it becomes very large so it is better to avoid doing that). Maybe it is better to show code from `at Invoice.GetInvoicesByStatusAndDate(Invoice.java:66)` to find the root of problem

Comment: @НиколайМитропольский you are right, its a large xml string but i have also another class which does almost the same thing but that class works fine. i will put the code soon.

Comment: Generally if you are putting data from database to RAM (for example if you are reading all entities from database and writing them to *String-in-RAM* ) then sooner or later you will run out of memory. So if you want to convert database content to XML - then write XML directly to file, not to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not having enough memory to operate. You can set maximum heap size using -Xmx jvm option.

e.g. If your program is an executable jar, to allocate maximum 80MB you can use

```
$java -Xmx80m -jar executatable.jar
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html for more information

Comment: how much can i allocate if my remote machine has only 4gb? since i dont how much my class requires when i execute it,

Comment: Well you could technically allocated very close to 4GB leaving memory for OS to operate. But unless you are working on data intensive app, this is not recommended. Have you tried profiling your app? I suggest that you also look at code whether your program actually could handle the data coming in without running out of memory. A good point to get started would be the dump "java_pid3696.hprof" you got when program crashed.

Comment: i managed to sort out the problem i just allocated 1028 and it worked. FYI i did download the data dump but by then i had already fixed the problem . thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

@curiousprgrammer, i set the -Xmx80m to -Xmx1028m it seems like the issue is more realted to jvm then the actual pysical memory.